# Minio minio.error.SignatureDoesNotMatch thrown with try-except

Tags: python, minio

I am using the python package for the minio server. I have the following piece of code that is used for a login:

```py
from minio.error import [...], SignatureDoesNotMatch, [...]

def login(self):
    try: 
        self.user = Minio(MINIO_CONFIG['MINIO_ENDPOINT'], 
                                access_key=self.username, 
                                secret_key=self.password, 
                                secure=MINIO_CONFIG['MINIO_SECURE'])
        return {"msg":"User is now logged in", "status": "OK"}
     except SignatureDoesNotMatch as err: 
        return {"msg": err.message, "status":"F"}
     except ResponseError as err: 
        return {'msg': err.message, 'status': "F"}
     except InvalidAccessKeyId as err: 
        return {"msg": err.message, "status":"F"}
     except InvalidArgument as err: 
        return {"msg": err.message, "status":"F"}
     except InvalidArgumentError as err: 
        return {"msg": err.message, "status":"F"}
```

The issue I am facing is that even though I do have in the `try-except` the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` in case the credentials are not correct, it does not return me the msg it should but it throws an `minio.error.SignatureDoesNotMatch` instead. Why does that happen?

The error I get:

```
minio.error.SignatureDoesNotMatch: SignatureDoesNotMatch: message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
```

Comment: How are you import SignatureDoesNotMatch?

Comment: updated the description of the question. not you should see how the exception is imported

Comment: Could you print the stack trace.

Comment: Please check the updated question and let me know if this is what you wanted @frozenOne

Comment: Is this a typo, that you don't have an ending bracket here - ```return {"msg":"User is now logged in", "status": "OK"```?

Comment: Yes this is wrong just here. In the actual code it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fine, looking at the code, this will never run into an error on it's own, regardless of the credentials provided. It will only run into an error when it makes an API call, or when you invoke methods like `list_buckets`, `list_objects` etc using this `self.user` instance, from outside this block.

I think what you're trying to do is-- invoking methods like `list_buckets` etc from outside this encapsulation-- somewhere else not this part of the code, and then they produce this error and propagate them to the console. You cannot encapsulate the `MinIO` instance within `try-catch` and catch errors while you make use of stuff like `self.user.list_buckets()` from outside this `try-catch` block.

Comment: In that case, if for example I use the `list_buckets()` in the try-catch it should throw the actual one of these errors, right?

Comment: Then it will catch that error and return the error message.

Comment: Yes, wrap your external calls from in try catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to check if the credentials are correct without having to call a functionality like `list_buckets`?

Comment: I don't think so, I might be wrong though. But it doesn't invoke the API unless you use some function from what I've learned about `minio-py` by looking at the library and working with it.